# passing a function as an argument in python

Tags: python, lambda

Suppose I want to calculate the following `f(f(...f(x)..)` .
Basically many times function of itself.
Currently I am doing the following to achieve this result (and to return all the intermediate steps):

```
def iterator(function, x, n=4):
    x = float(x)
    arr = []
    for i in range(n + 1):
        arr.append(x)
        x = function(x)

    return arr

def funcM(x):
    return x / 4 + 12
```

and then I am passing my function `funcM` as an argument:
`print iterator(funcM, 100, 5)`.

There is nothing wrong with this approach, and calculations are correct.

But is there a way to do the same without defining function `funcM` ?
May be passing lambda function as an argument to iterator function (Sorry if it does not make sense, I do not really know what lambda functions are).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A lambda function (or more accurately, a lambda *expression*) is simply a function you can define on-the-spot, right where you need it. For example,

```
f = lambda x: x * 2
```

is *exactly* the same thing as

```
def f(x):
    return x * 2
```

And when I say exactly, I mean it -- they disassemble to the same bytecode. The only difference between the two is that the one defined in the second example has a name.

Lambda expressions become useful because creating one is not a statement, which means that, as others have already answered, you can do

```
print iterator(lambda x: x / 4 + 12, 100, 5)
```

to get precisely what you want.

The main difference between lambda expressions and regular functions, however, is that lambdas are more limited. Lambdas can only contain *expressions*, not statements. An expression is anything you can put on the right side of an `=` assignment. (if you want to get more pedantic, Python defines an expression as http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html )

What this means is a lambda expression can not assign to a variable (in fact, it can't have local variables at all, other than its parameters). It can't print (unless it calls another function that does). It can't have a for loop, a while loop, an if test (other than the ternary operator `x if cond else y`), or a try/except block.

If you need to do any of those, just define a regular function. In fact, any time you think you want to use a lambda, think twice. Wouldn't the code be more readable if you used a regular function? Isn't that lambda expression something you'd like to reuse somewhere else in your code?

In the end, always do what leads to the most readable and maintainable code. *There is no difference between lambdas and normal functions as far as performance is concerned.*

Comment: Note that printing isn't a problem in Python 3, since `print` is changed to a function.

Comment: If funcM() in the example were more complicated, including statements not allowed in a lambda, would there be any way to pass a function in Python without declaring it separately? JavaScript and Dart allow you to just pass an anonymous function as an argument, for example. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can just use lambda expressions. They are made for this.

```
iterator(lambda x: x/4+12, 100, 5)
```

Words from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

> Lambdas are usually used to create small, anonymous functions.
>   Actually, they are just a syntatic sugar to define functions. The
>   lambda expression above is exactly the same as your function, only
>   without a name.

If you wish to learn more, Here is some good read:

http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html
[Why use lambda functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259322/why-use-lambda-functions)