# How to write lambda with no return and no arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I want to pass a function/lambda to a method and then call it in python 2.7:

```
def foo(f):
    f()
```

I tried many ways but didnt find the correct syntax. For example this

```
foo(lambda: print("hallo"))
```

results in

```
    foo(lambda: print("hallo"))
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know that this works:

```
foo(lambda x: None)
```

But I dont know how to make the lambda actually do something and at the same time return `None`

Related: [A suitable 'do nothing' lambda expression in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738412/a-suitable-do-nothing-lambda-expression-in-python), though the lambdas in the answer just do nothing :(

Comment: which version of python are you on? this works fine on python 3.6

Comment: @Nullman 2.7 sorry, will add that to the question

Comment: `print` is a statement in python 2 and thus can't be used in a lambda.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I want to lambda to execute a statement, this is not possible?

Comment: @Aran-Fey anyhow `print` was just an example, consider setting the value of a global variable as a different example

Comment: You can't do that in a lambda, no. (Well, you *can*, but you really shouldn't.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey when I shouldnt then what should i do instead?

Comment: Use a real function instead of a lambda.

Comment: @Aran-Fey [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21035557/4117728) answer claims that a lambda **is** just a function, so i though i was on the right track. My goal is just to write it inline together with the call to `foo` instead of having to define a function. Anyhow, with the dupe my problem is solved, I will try to be more pythonic later :P