# Tkinter change option menu based on radio button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a gui interface that has among other things a drop down menu that should be different based on a radio button selection. The menu should change as many times as I click the radio buttons, and the dropdown menu should work as normal once the user has made a radio button selection.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def get_menu_one(*args):
    options = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    dropdown['menu'].delete(0,'end')
    for option in options:
        dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=option, command=option_var.set())


def get_menu_two(*args):
    options = ['d', 'e', 'f']
    dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
    for option in options:
        dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=option, command=option_var.set())


var = IntVar()
r_button1 = Radiobutton(root, text='Choice 1', variable=var, value=1, command=get_menu_one)
r_button1.pack()
r_button2 = Radiobutton(root, text='Choice 2', variable=var, value=2, command=get_menu_two)
r_button2.pack()

option_var = StringVar()
option_var.set('Make a selection')
dropdown = OptionMenu(root, option_var, ['Make a selection'])
dropdown.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the following code, the radio buttons work in that the options are now displayed in the dropdown menu. However, even though the menu options are correctly displayed when the button is pushed, it doesn't really do anything. When the user clicks on an option, it doesn't get selected in the way that a dropdown menu normally functions. For example, if the user selects 'choice 1,' then the dropdown menu will display 'c' and if the user then tries to choose a or b, it won't be updated.

Comment: I tried this and it gives me a ''can't delete Tcl command'' error when clicking the radio buttons multiple times. Also, the dropdown menu doesn't behave normally. When selecting an option, it doesn't seem to be selected. The entry in the menu after selecting doesn't change from ''Make a selection'' to 'a' for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=option, command=option_var.set())`

In your code, you forgot to pass argument to the `set` function.

You need to change `get_menu_one` and `get_menu_two` to set the current option:

```py
def get_menu_one(*args):
    options = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    dropdown['menu'].delete(0,'end')
    for option in options:
        dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=option, command=lambda op=option:option_var.set(op))
    option_var.set(options[0])


def get_menu_two(*args):
    options = ['d', 'e', 'f']
    dropdown.children['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
    for option in options:
        dropdown.children['menu'].add_command(label=option, command=lambda op=option:option_var.set(op))
    option_var.set(options[0])
```

---

***Note:***

If you noticed, the two function are very similar to one another...

You could combine the two functions into one to improve versatility and readability:

```py
def change_menu(options):
    dropdown['menu'].delete(0,'end')
    for option in options:
        dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=option, command=lambda op=option:option_var.set(op))
    option_var.set(options[0])
```

And then change the definition of the `Radiobutton`s:

```py
r_button1 = Radiobutton(root, text='Choice 1', variable=var, value=1, command=lambda:change_menu(['a', 'b', 'c']))
r_button1.pack()
r_button2 = Radiobutton(root, text='Choice 2', variable=var, value=2, command=lambda:change_menu(['d', 'e', 'f']))
r_button2.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. One question, it seems to be necessary to include lambda op=option:option_var.set(op). If I try command=option_var.set(option) I get the ''doesn't get selected'' behaviour again. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: When you use the parenthesis you are calling the function, whereas when you are using lambda you are passing a pointer to the lambda function which includes a call to the `option_var.set` function

Comment: You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035437/passing-a-function-as-an-argument-in-python) more if you want.